# Autoloading PHP files in WordPress themes

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been loading files in my WordPress themes using this snippet of code

```
/* https://gist.github.com/theandystratton/5924570*/
foreach ( glob( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/lib/*.php' ) as $file ) { include $file; }`
```

This is all that is in my `functions.php` file and all of the files that are used are inside of the `/lib/` directory. Files such as `customize.php`, `load-assets.php`, etc. `customize.php` is for all code related to adding settings and controls to the customizer and the `load-assets.php` is where we load our assets (js and css).

So we are in the process of getting a code review and the reviewer suggested I manually include each file using `require get_template_directory() . '/path/to-file.php';`

Is there an advantage for doing this? What do you do? What should you do?

Comment: just how many files are you talking about here? it's pointless/useless to load (say) 500 files, of which you'd only be using 10 or 15 at any given time. That's a lot of wasted load/parse time.

Comment: imagine situation that external user was able to upload his own php file to this folder, what will happen?

Comment: Good point @Lashane I had not thought of that.

Comment: @MarcB Only between 5-10 files.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the below code to `include` all of the files in `includes` dir.

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'AT_BASE_DIR' ) )
    define( 'AT_BASE_DIR', trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) );

foreach ( glob( AT_BASE_DIR . 'includes/*.php' ) as $file ) {
    include_once $file;
}
```